# pygame_gui events not firing

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-gui

I am trying to do something I have done before with no issue, that is use pygame_gui with pygame to detect when a UI button has been clicked.

```py
import pygame as pg
import pygame_gui as pgg
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
import csv


character_dict = ()
last_character_gui = None


def main():
    pg.init()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    gui_manager = pgg.UIManager((800, 600))
    app_running = True
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    open_file_button = pgg.elements.UIButton(relative_rect=pg.Rect(0, 0, 800, 50),
                                             manager=gui_manager,
                                             text="open file")
    scroll_container = pgg.elements.ui_scrolling_container.UIScrollingContainer(relative_rect=pg.Rect(0, 50, 800, 2000),
                                                                                manager=gui_manager)
    while app_running:
        time_delta = clock.tick(60) / 100.0
        gui_manager.update(time_delta)
        gui_manager.draw_ui(screen)
        pg.display.update()

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pgg.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED:
                if event.ui_element == open_file_button:
                    file = prompt_file()
                    character_dict = populate_characters(file)
                    populate_gui(scroll_container, gui_manager)
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                app_running = False
```

The problem is that no `UI_BUTTON_PRESSED` event is ever firing. I have tried tracking the event output and it simply never occurs. I have tried reading the documentation, but alas I cannot see what I am doing wrong here or where the issues might be. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: have you tried `print(event.type)` and seeing which event is being captured? and then doing `print(pgg.UI_BUTTON_PRESSED)`  and checking if this two values are the same?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. The event simply does not fire when I click on the button. The only event that fires is the mouse down event.

Comment: are you sure the `UI_BUTTON_PRESSED` is an event of `pg` instead of an event of `pgg`?  Because in the loop you are cycling over events in `pg.event`  but according to your code `UI_BUTTON_PRESSED` belongs to `pgg`

Comment: Ah, thank you! that was the clue I needed to figure this out. The event needed to be passed to a function that was part of pgg first, gui_manager.process_events(event). Did not see this in the docs. Now things are working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UI_BUTTON_PRESSED` is not a [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) event, but a [Pygame GUI](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/v_069/index.html) event. See [GUI events - `UI_BUTTON_PRESSED`](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/v_069/events.html?highlight=UI_BUTTON_PRESSED#uibutton-ui-button-pressed). The Pygame GUI events needs to be processed with [`process_events`](https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/v_069/pygame_gui.html?highlight=process_events#pygame_gui.ui_manager.UIManager.process_events):

```py
for event in pg.event.get():
    gui_manager.process_events(event)
```